# Linking domain name to a google drive link

Tags: dns, web, google-drive-api, web-hosting

I have obtained a domain name from bigrock and want to host the webpage through google drive. I have also uploaded the webpage on google drive and have the webpage link  too. Now the question is how can I link my domain name to the link google drive.

I also know the iframe concept but for that also I am not sure how to host that html file. I dont have a hosting service.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to visit something like `http://www.yournewdomainname.com` in your browser and have it show your website that is hosted in Google Drive at a URL something like `googledrive.com/host/.../your-page.html`.

I don't think it's possible to do this without an web host of some sort. DNS can point your domain to an IP address but not a URL.

The only alternative I can think of is to point your domain at a server which is configured to respond with an HTTP redirect to your Google Drive page. There'd still be a web host involved, but it'd have much less load in this case because the actual content isn't there.

Edit: apparently there are some services that can do this for you. Try searching for something like "free dns url redirection".

Comment: okk, i am looking into it ... Do u have any idea about freehosting.com ?? I set up an account there and tried to host it from there but could not do it. I updated the nameservers on bigrock as per the ones provided from freehosting

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with such services, I was just suggesting a possible option for you